# How to go one folder back and run in docker

Tags: shell

I want to run various commands of docker from docker.sh file.But to run one command i have to go back one folder outside means parent directory.How can i do this.This is my docker.sh file.

```
sudo -i service elasticsearch start
redis-server
celery -A flask_crud_api.celery worker --loglevel=info  #This command runs from one folder back.
python3 app.py
```

How to write this command such that it goes one folder back and then runs:

```
celery -A flask_crud_api.celery worker --loglevel=info
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just specify the relative path?

```
../celery -A flask_crud_api.celery worker --loglevel=info
```

The `../` will go back 1 directory relative to the current working directory.

Comment: Thanku I will try it